# Use slug rather than ID in vue js

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I am trying to use the slug to access the details of a model in my `django` + `vue3` project.

#### Backend

In my `models.py` I have

```python
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField


class Magazine(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=['title'])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In my `serialisers.py`

```python
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Magazine


class MagazineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Magazine
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'description',
            'slug'
        )
```

In my `views.py`

```python
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework import viewsets

from .models import Magazine
from .serializers import MagazineSerializer


class MagazineViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MagazineSerializer
    queryset = Magazine.objects.all()
```

#### Frontend

In my `router/index.js` I have

```js
  {
    path: '/magazines/:slug',
    name: 'Magazine',
    component: Magazine,
    meta: {
        requireLogin: true
      }
  }
```

While in my `Magazine.vue` page I have

```js
<template>
    <div class="bph-content">
        <h1>{{ magazine.title }}</h1>
        <h1>{{ magazine.slug }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: 'Magazine', 
    data() {
        return {
            magazine: {}
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.getMagazine()
    },

    methods: {
        async getMagazine() {
            
            const magazineSlug = this.$route.params.slug
            await axios
                .get(`/api/v1/magazines/${magazineSlug}`)
                .then(response => {
                    this.magazine = response.data
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

At `http://localhost:8080/magazines/<slug-magazine>` I get a 404 error, but at `http://localhost:8080/magazines/<id>` I get details of the various journals correctly (even if I'm using slug!)

How can I get the magazine details at `http://localhost:8080/magazines/<slug-magazine>`?

Comment: Frontend is irrelevant. It doesn't matter if you call it `id` or `slug` on frontend. It's up to your backend. It should accept slugs in api requests.

Comment: your suggestion was enough to show me the right direction to follow. I fixed django serializer and view and solved the problem. Thank you very much! Now I don't know what to do with the question: whether to delete it or answer it myself

Comment: Glad you solved it. Self-answers are welcome on SO.Consider updating the question to reflect your case with the backend with relevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Estus Flask suggestion I was able to solve the problem.

I changed `view.py`

```python
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework import viewsets

from .models import Magazine
from .serializers import MagazineSerializer


class MagazineViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MagazineSerializer
    queryset = Magazine.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

and `serializers.py`

```python
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Magazine


class MagazineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Magazine
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'description',
            'slug'
        )
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }
```

This way I can reach the url correctly!